# How to force text mode only on the SO login?

Tags: ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with GDM3 by default but i like use and view only text mode with best stable packages. In the main splash i remove the graphical loader removing the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="" values, now the splash show text only, but when finish show the GDM with the graphical login.

How to configure the system to show only the default gnu/linux text mode only login? and how made to start automatically the startx on success login?, i can lock the screen using tty1? (Ctrl + Alt + F1) or similar?

I don't use other distributions (although I like arch and fedora) because of the stability of the packages, automatic updates without affecting the execution of the services and the long-term support.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

sudo systemctl set-default multi-user

Please check this page:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-enable-gui-on-boot-in-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux-desktop

Comment: Thanks, but after login can not start the ubuntu desktop. I try `startx`, `startx && xinit` and `gnome-session` but can not start the normal desktop.

Comment: You can start gdm3 from terminal: sudo systemctl start gdm3

Comment: if you want it ALWAYS running even though you want to be at the console, use systemctl to enable it.

Comment: But `gdm3` start graphical login, i need use terminal login and start the graphical enviroment desktop without the type the user and password again.